# How can I rotate labels in a Dendrogram when using pre-clustered data?

Tags: visualization, cluster-analysis

I have some pre-clustered data that I want to visualize with `Dendrogram`.  I am using `Dendrogram` purely for visualization in this case, not for clustering.

`Dendrogram` takes pre-clustered data as a tree.  Here's an example:

```
tree = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/NMCS7gbb"]
Dendrogram[tree]
```

[image]

The dendrogram is plainly unreadable because the labels are too wide.  I want to rotate them by 90 degrees. How can I do this?

---

One way is to rotate the labels in `tree`.  In this particular tree they are in the form `Placed[label, Below]`.  They can be rotated either as `Placed[Rotate[label, Pi/2], Below]` or as `Placed[label, Below, Rotate[#,Pi/2]&]`.  Only the former way works.  In general, the vertex label may or may not be wrapped in `Placed`. Both situations need to be handled.

Is there a less cumbersome solution than this?

---

I am aware of the Hierarchical Clustering packages and its `DendrogramPlot`, which can easily accomplish this. This question is specifically about `Dendrogram`.

Comment: Would something like `Rotate[Dendrogram[tree, Left], -Pi/2]` work for you?